# I got a strange banner on Chrome asking me to "update my account". Is it legitimate, or is it some sort of malware?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, malware, google-search, kaspersky

**tl;dnr:**
A vaguely written banner appeared while I was searching on Google (description in 1st paragraph), asking me to update my account, and not much more, which didn't seem right. What is it, is this due to malware on my machine, a phishing scam, a problem w/ Kaspersky and/or Windows Defender, or is it benign?

**What happened/what it looked like:**
While searching on google the other day, a banner appeared on the top of the search (as part of the web page, not part of Chrome itself). I didn't grab a screenshot, so I can only describe it roughly. It had a blue shield icon on the left, and a couple of buttons in the right (along the lines of "no, thanks" and "more info"), and some text in the center asking me to "update your account for added security and transparency". When I continued to search in Google in the same tab, this header would stay, but if I closed the tab, the header would go away for a while.

**What I did about it:** It only popped up a couple times on one of my machines, and I never saw it appear on any other machine I ran Chrome on. Because it was so vague and it came out of nowhere, I researched if google was updating how their accounts worked, and I found no information about a Google account update outside of something for adwords or adsense, which I don't use. When I tried using Chrome's dev tools to inspect the elements, I found the buttons didn't link anywhere, maybe because they would just run a script. The blue shield icon was weird, because it linked to the url for an image in Google images (like `http://someplace.com/a/url/path/anIcon.png`). The actual google icon actually had a hard link (like `/a/file/path/googleLogo.png`) to somewhere on a google server. Because this seemed suspicious, I never actually clicked either button. The popup managed to appear after I did a full scan in safe mode w/ Kaspersky. I had also recently updated Kaspersky, and after this install, it seems that my Windows 10 machine didn't initially acknowledge that Kaspersky is on, and insists on turning on Defender as well. The banner hasn't popped up in a couple days, not since I reinstalled Kaspersky with a fresh install (which seems to coincide w/ my machine acknowledging the presence of Kaspersky and it turning off defender). However I'm still a bit worried that something was already on my PC, causing this to happen.

**Possible explanations:** I can think of a few possible reasons for this happening. The first is that I was prompted to update Kaspersky the day before. Except the update wasn't the usual new definitions, it actually asked me to reinstall the software. There was a five minute window where suddenly both Kaspersky and Windows Defender were both down, as I didn't expect Kaspersky to totally go down. Perhaps something managed to slip by during this downtime? The second possible reason is I was looking into getting Google App Engine running for a tutorial I was following. I didn't realize it was pay to use, so I stopped partway through the setup process. Is it possible it was just Google trying to get me to finish the setup? Finally, it seems this was around the time for a chrome update, so was it just a prompt for me to update? It was so vague about what it wanted to update I wasn't willing to use the prompts it gave and risk getting infected.

**My current Chrome Setup:** In terms of extensions, the only ones I have currently installed are Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Docs, Kaspersky Protection, and RikaiKun. Kaspersky Protection and Rikaikun are disabled.

Anyway, thanks for your time, hopefully something comes of this, and hopefully it was just an unnecessarily vague prompt to update Chrome.

Comment: Seems like the simplest thing you should do is verify your running the current version of Chrome.  If you are disregard the message, if not, you should update Chrome.  I will be honest your question is very long, has way to much information, that really isn't vital to your question (which makes it hard to follow).

Comment: I find the question lacks meaty details.  What did the hyperlinks say when hovered over?  "like http://someplace.com/a/url/path/anIcon.png" is too vague for us to know whether the domain is Google-owned.  The description of the banner sounds vaguely Google-ish, so I get the vague impression that there is a reasonably possible chance it was legit.  However, I can't feel confident about that without more detailed information. \n If your system security is critical, prepare to take heavy measures (like an OS re-install).  Else, if your system seems clean, you might wanna just keep an eye open